# Hide values from variables

Tags: php

I've been trying to hide the results returning from that variables:

```php
$fileddataname = $row["dateupload"];
$date1 = new DateTime("$fileddataname");
$date2 = new DateTime('now');
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);

$years = $diff->format("%y anos");
$months = $diff->format("%m meses");
$days = $diff->format("%d dias");
$hours = $diff->format("%h horas");
$minutes = $diff->format("%i minutos");
$seconds = $diff->format("%s segundos");

if ($years == 0){
 echo $months.' '.$days.' '.$hours.' '.$minutes.' '.$seconds.' ';
}
if ($months == 0){
 echo $days,' '.$hours.' '.$minutes.' '.$seconds.' ';
}
elseif ($days == 0){
 echo $hours.' '.$minutes.' '.$seconds.' ';
}
elseif ($hours == 0){
 echo $minutes.' '.$seconds.' ';
}
elseif ($minutes == 0){
 echo $seconds.'';
}
```

Data format:

```
2020-02-21 13:58
```

I need to hide the values with 0 and the word around:

```
0 years 0 days 33 minutes 22 seconds.
```

To:

```
33 minutes 22 seconds.
```

Comment: Full code: https://pastebin.com/FyFS7KH0

Comment: I don't understand. Do you need to only remove the zero value and the word, even if it's a day, minute, or second? Example: "2 days 0 minutes 0 seconds." becomes "2 days"

Comment: @Lucius yes :) just hide the non important text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Ok, it was really ugly, I made a better option based on [Quynh Xuan Nguyen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8775139/quynh-xuan-nguyen)'s answer :

```php
$date1 = new DateTime('2020-02-22 13:58');
$date2 = new DateTime('now');
$diff = date_diff($date1, $date2);

$times = [
    '%y' => ['year', 'years'],
    '%m' => ['month', 'months'],
    '%d' => ['day', 'days'],
    '%h' => ['hour', 'hours'],
    '%i' => ['minute', 'minutes'],
    '%s' => ['second', 'seconds'],
];
$diff_times = '';

foreach ($times as $key => $value) {
    $d = $diff->format($key);
    if (!empty($d)) {
        $diff_times .= (!empty($diff_times) ? ' ': '') . $d . ' ' . ($d == 1 ? $value[0] : $value[1]);
    }
}

$diff_times = !empty($diff_times) ? $diff_times . '.' : '';

echo $diff_times;
```

**OLDER ANSWER:**

Not very beautiful, but it works. Basically you create a variable and stores on it only non zero values:

```php
    $date1 = new DateTime("2021-02-22 13:58");
    $date2 = new DateTime('now');
    $diff = date_diff($date1, $date2);
    
    $diff_times = "";
    
    $diff_times .= $diff->format("%y") ? $diff->format("%y years") : '';
    $diff_times .= $diff->format("%m") ? $diff->format(" %m months") : '';
    $diff_times .= $diff->format("%d") ? $diff->format(" %d days") : '';
    $diff_times .= $diff->format("%h") ? $diff->format(" %h hours") : '';
    $diff_times .= $diff->format("%i") ? $diff->format(" %i minutes") : '';
    $diff_times .= $diff->format("%s") ? $diff->format(" %s seconds") : '';

    echo $diff_times;
```

Comment: thank you http://i.epvpimg.com/3dHdcab.png
Real time to solve all this code haha

Comment: Hahaha, nice! @AndréSantos please, use my newer version, it's better than the first.

Comment: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\profile.php on line (last line)

Comment: @AndréSantosThe code block from $diff_times = ""; to echo $diff_times is exactly my parse_diff. The final result will miss the dot character.

Comment: @QuynhXuanNguyen you're right, I'll update it

Comment: @Lucius it's working now on the 2nd version, thank you, really good! :D

Comment: I've got more 1 challenge if you want, how to show 1 minute and 1 year instead of 1 years 1 minutes <3 :D

Comment: @AndréSantos take a look at the new version, now there's an array of singular and plural values: https://3v4l.org/NmlkP

Comment: 8 hours 23 minutes 1 second. <3

Answer (score -2):

```php
<?php

function parse_diff($diff)
{
    $result = '';
    foreach ([
        '%y' => 'years',
        '%m' => 'months',
        '%d' => 'days',
        '%h' => 'hours',
        '%i' => 'minutes',
        '%s' => 'seconds',
    ] as $symbol => $text) {
        $number = $diff->format($symbol);
        if ($number > 0) {
            $result .= " $number $text";
        }
    }
    return $result === '' ? $result : $result.'.';
}

$now = Carbon\Carbon::now();
$aPastMoment = now()->subYears(1)->sub(5, 'days');
$diff = $now->diff($aPastMoment);

echo parse_diff($diff);
```

Comment: Sorry for the downvote. This makes assumptions about the users implementations (ie: carbon) and is a code only post, meaning the user cannot learn from it.

Comment: First, question doesn't show what type $diff is. Second, this function is simple, give a lot of comments just makes it messy.

Comment: In some case (simple enough), describe your thought by code is a good idea. I don't think code only post is a problem in which user can not learn from it.

Comment: First, You can't make assumptions based on unseen code. Second, What you consider messy, is actually required here to be a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer --- Just because something looks 'simple' to you, does not mean it does to the person having issues.

Comment: @QuynhXuanNguyen on my first comment I show the pastebin with all the code, thank you for your reply. https://pastebin.com/FyFS7KH0

Comment: It's up to you. I just give something I think it's helpful. For me, this sample is simple enough. Someone can ask about the code if they need more information and I will provide as much as I can. It may not be helpful for you. Because you show me your opinion and I also just talk about my opinion. Btw, $diff is an instance of DateInterval which some one can create by pure PHP and Carbon give us quick way to have an example. @Jesse

Comment: @AndréSantos You can try my parse_diff function by passing $diff into it.

Comment: @QuynhXuanNguyen -- You want the user to install an entire PHP extension (Carbon) to do a simple date function. Its simply wrong. Case closed.

Comment: @Jesse I don't say that I want. I just give an example, anyone can use anyway to create their diff.